# Cannot see the ObjectAid UML Explorer plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, objectaid

I managed to install the ObjectAid UML explorer in my  JUNO Eclipse. Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.1. But when I tried to create a UML diagram from the class files that I have, I cannot see the ObjectAid UML as you can see in the image here: [image]

But when I try to uninstall the softwares, I can see the ObjectAid UML in the list of installed software. Does anybody know why it is so? Should I do anything to activate it? I'm 100% sure that the installation was correct as I followed the steps from the official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [ObjectAid One-Minute Introduction](http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram) user manual

> First you create an empty class diagram with the 'New' wizard. To get there, you can simply press Ctrl+N in the package or folder where you want to create your class diagram.

You should search for "Class Diagram" in the wizard.

I can't confirm this on Juno, but it works for me in Kepler.

Comment: Yeha, actually I followed the same. But I can't see the plugin there even though I installed it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your eclipse post the installation? Try restarting your eclipse with a -clean option. Sometimes the workspace settings won't reflect the new installation immediately. You should be able to see the UMLDiagram. if you are still not able to see it, try typing Class Diagram in the wizard and see if it appears. Checkout the snapshot at [my post](http://evverythingatonce.blogspot.in/2016/04/tech-talk-reverse-uml-generator-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it removing the plugin completely and installing it again, but this time making sure that I skip the License Required plugins. Another factor than can help is to run Eclipse as an administrator because the puglins folder are located in ProgramFiles.

[objectaid uml explorer without licensed plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnMVp.png)